# Linq Select list of dynamic properties into another Object?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of properties which will be dynamic and can frequently change on each request.

```
var dynamicFields = new List<string>{ "UserName", "UserEmail" };
```

I have an another list of class which contains all dynamicFields and other fields.

```
var staticFields = new List<StaticFields>
    {
        new StaticFields {UserName = "Chandra", UserDepartment = "IT", UserCity = "Bangalore", UserEmail = "abc@gmail.com"},
        new StaticFields {UserName = "Sekar", UserDepartment = "CSE", UserCity = "Bangalore", UserEmail = "xyz@gmail.com"},
        new StaticFields {UserName = "Dilip", UserDepartment = "IT", UserCity = "Bangalore", UserEmail = "cba@gmail.com"}
    };

public class StaticFields
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public string UserDepartment {get; set;}
    public string UserCity {get; set;}
    public string UserEmail {get; set;}
    //etc..
}
```

--

I have to select only fields are in dynamicFields list.

So how can I achieve this in C# either using for loops or using LINQ ?

Edit:

Purpose is used to display only selected columns in display. I'm using SP to fetch all the data from DB. It's a legacy code from db, so I don't have any access to change DB stored procedures.

I have tried below code in JS.

```
var i;
var properties = [
 'UserName',
 'UserEmail'
];
for (i = 0; i < properties.length; i += 1) {
 document.writeln(properties[i] + ': ' + another_object[properties[i]]);
}
```

I have to convert this code to C#

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What are you actually using them for? Chances are you will be using reflection to do this but that would be inefficient and possibly overkill for what you need it for (i.e GetProperties then get values that aren't default values)

Comment: Why do you want to only select certain columns? Are you planning to reduce the query overload or you just need to display certain columns? Also please show the code you tried but not working / complete yet.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the purpose and what I have done so far.

Comment: I guess you are using some sort of datagrid and only want to display certain columns to do that you could use many approches like wrapper objects, autogeneratingcolumns or use the attribute browseable.

Comment: SO you are expecting the result would be a list of anonymous type that can be accessed from something like `result[i]["UserName"]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [dynamic LINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) with proper extensions:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this DynamicClass dynamicObject, string propName)
{
    if (dynamicObject == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dynamicObject");
    }

    var type = dynamicObject.GetType();
    var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public 
                                 | BindingFlags.Instance 
                                 | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
    var prop = props.FirstOrDefault(property => property.Name == propName);
    if (prop == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Specified property doesn't exist.");
    }

    return (T)prop.GetValue(dynamicObject, null);
}

public static string ToDynamicSelector(this IList<string> propNames)
{
   if (!propNames.Any()) 
       throw new ArgumentException("You need supply at least one property");
   return string.Format("new({0})", string.Join(",", propNames));
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
...

var result = staticFields.AsQueryable().Select(dynamicFields.ToDynamicSelector())
                                       .Cast<DynamicClass>();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.GetValue<string>(list[0]); // outputs all user names
}
```

Remarks:

1. Dynamic LINQ supports EF, so you can fetch data directly from DB
2. You can serialize `result` into JSON without any problems - `DynamicClass` is built with properties.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Thanks for remarks too. I'm trying